# how to code a on click event function for automatically generated button

Tags: php, jquery, button, input, onclick

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['take-attendance'])){
$date = date("d/m");
echo'<center><table><tr><th> Student-Id </th> <th> Name </th> <th>'.$date.'</th></tr>';

foreach($sheet_data as $row) {

    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td> <input type = "button"  value = "A" name = "'.$row['id'].'" id = "'.$row['id'].'" class = "apbutton" ></td></tr>';

}       
 echo '</table></center>';

} 

?>

<script>

$(".apbutton").live("click", function() {
    var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(buttonId);
}); 


</script>
```

> here i've generated a input button with class apbutton nd i'm trying to get the button id 
>   but this is not working please tell me where i'm wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait for the code to be ready. (As `.live` is deprecated, I switched to `.on`)

```
$(function(){

    $(".apbutton").on("click", function() {
        var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(buttonId);
    });

});
```

Comment: @user2492144 pleasure